# How can I combine multimatch query with a boolquery in elasticsearch?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I am trying to write a query that will run a query coupled with a multimatch query (possibly with an empty value) in elasticsearch. Consider the following data example where each item is a document in elasticsearch. Additional fields are redacted to reduce complexity in the example.

```
[
  {
    "name": "something",
    "categories": ["python", "lib"]
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "categories": ["python", "lib"]
  },
  {
    "name": "another",
    "categories": ["javascript", "lib"]
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is writing a bool query where categories must match `python` and `lib`, and then run a multimatch query on that. So my code structure is:

```golang
// assume cat.Filter folds []string{"python", "lib"}
filters := []elastic.Query{}
for _, ff := range cat.Filter {
  filters = append(filters, elastic.NewTermQuery("categories", ff))
}
// create multimatch query
e := elastic.NewMultiMatchQuery("something").Fuzziness("2")
// create a query that will match all fields in an array
q := elastic.NewBoolQuery().Must(filters...).Filter(e)
hits, err := client.Search().Index(index).Query(q).Size(limit).Do(ctx)
```

If I run this query with as is, then I get back 1 hit as expected. But if I change the multimatch query to `e := elastic.NewMultiMatchQuery("some")`, then I get back an empty array.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

- When using `e := elastic.NewMultiMatchQuery("some").Fuzziness("2")`, return an array of 1 item that matches `something`
- When I set `e := elastic.NewMultiMatchQuery("").Fuzziness("2")`, return an array of two items that match both categories for `python` and `lib`. (this works if i remove the multimatch array filter.

My issue is that I can do either or, but not both. I have a feeling because the `Must` is enforcing that `something` has to be an exact match, and `some` or `""` does not match that. Thats what I am trying to overcome. First match all the values in an array, and then query that.